# Google FCM in Edge browser : DOMException: Registration failed - push service error

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, microsoft-edge

I am trying to enable push notifications on my site.
Chrome browsers manage to get the token and notifications work fine.

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission().then(function () {
  messaging.getToken().then(function (currentToken) {
      sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.warn(err);
      setTokenSentToServer(false);
    });
});
```

But in enterprise browser Edge (109.0.1518.78 ) when getting the token i get the foloowing error.

```
DOMException: Registration failed - push service error
```

Comment: The latest version of Microsoft Edge is 112.0.1722.34. You can try upgrading to the latest version and testing again.

Comment: Updated the browser to the latest version (12.0.1722.34). Problem not solved, same error.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-WordPress-Plugin/issues/96#issuecomment-365427692), `DOMException: Registration failed - push service error` can be either caused by browser incompatibility or invalid `gcm_sender_id`. You can perform the provided 2 troubleshooting steps there.

Additionally, according to [this demo](https://webpushdemo.azurewebsites.net/), Microsoft Edge relies on the [Windows Push Notification Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview) (WNS) to deliver push messages. You may switch to WNS if this issue still occurs.

Comment: Notifications work on home PC in browsers: Chrome, EDGE  (12.0.1722.34).
From corporate network and PC: Chrome working, EDGE (12.0.1722.34) -  error (DOMException: Registration failed - push service error).

EDGE browsers of the same version.

Comment: @Alexsey If it only occurs on Edge on work PC with corporate network, your Edge is probably managed by your organization. In this case Google services for push messaging may be blocked. You can check your Edge group policies first at `edge://policy`.

Comment: I looked in the group policies (edge://policy) to block Google services for push messaging. The screen is blank. Talked to system administrators about blocking Google Servises in EDGE.... No blocking.
Don't know what the error is in getting the token...

Comment: @Alexsey I just tested on my device, and I've successfully got the token. Do you have your organization's account logged into Edge? If so, you can try using a local profile (no account logged in) or InPrivate mode to test again.

Comment: Yes, EDGE runs with an organization`s account. I tried run browser in Guest and InPrivate mode. Other error: DOMException: Registration failed - permission denied.
(Chromium currently does not support the Push API in incognito mode (https://crbug.com/401439). There is deliberately no way to feature-detect this, since incognito mode needs to be undetectable by websites.)

Comment: @Alexsey I got it. So, what's the test result with a guest profile or local profile? So far, this problem can probably be caused by organization's account restriction or Edge extensions. You can also check whether there's such an extension that blocked the service.